# Set vaadin table height to fit contents

Tags: css, vaadin

I use CustomLayout in my project to separate UI object and their style.

I have some problem with tables.

I define a div and I want the table's height set to div's height.

Which is the best way?

I thought:

```
table.setsizeFull() ;
table.setPageLength(0);
```

in the code, but the result is not what I want.
I want the table full sized in div's dimensions, both with or without elements inside.

Any suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure sure if it will help but "length" is spelled wrong in your example.

Comment: My fault, but it is not the problem, thanks!

Comment: I don't have a clue about Vaadin so this may not help but here's how you could do it with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/HVk5r/

Comment: @BillyMoat it is a little bit more complex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was solving a similar problem: I wanted a table to grow as I added rows to it.  I didn't care about its exact height, as long as it showed all the rows of data, and grew as I added rows.  I also wanted the table to always show some extra space at the bottom.

The core idea here is that I did three things:

- Do not call `setHeight()` for the table.
- I used `setPageLength()` to define table height by rows--by how many rows high the table should be.
- I called `requestRepaint()` on the element I resized.  If I resized a column element, I called it on the column element.  If I resized the table, I called it on the table.

Here's a generalized code sample showing how I solved this problem.  My code isn't complete, but it might help you get started.

```
public class MyClass extends Table {

    public MyClass(...)
    {
        this.setWidth("100%"); // fill parent <td>'s width, allows draggable sizing.
        // note: do NOT setHeight().

        setupColumns(); // details not shown here
        setupBehavior(); // details not shown (listeners, etc)
        addDataToTable(); // details not shown

        adjustHeight();
    }

    // I also have a function to add rows to the table when 
        // a button is clicked.  That function calls adjustHeight() (shown below).

    public void adjustHeight()
    {
        this.setPageLength(this.getItemIds().size() + 1);
        this.requestRepaint();
    }
}
```

[EDIT/FOLLOW-UP] I've found that using this method tends to cause unnecessary scroll bars to be rendered on tables if you are using `setColumnExpandRatio()` (dynamic column widths).  So just as a heads-up, you should use fixed width columns (`setColumnWidth()`) if you use the  trick I showed above.